# Generate 10,000 markers with good performance with layer group leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, leaflet, openstreetmap

Hello I need help I have an application that I need to generate 10k of markers and I can't use the cluster after the client wants all the points on the map, I even used a library: https://github.com/eJuke/Leaflet.Canvas- However, it is limited and does not work resources that I need and also does not remove the markers when requested.
The other option I found was to put everything in a layergroup he did well but the performance is horrible I would like to know if I can improve my performance follow my code below

```
  var cm = dtMuc[3][0];
var x = 10;
var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
for (var i=0; i < dtMuc[0].length; i++){
  if(cm == dtMuc[3][i]){
    url = L.icon({
      iconUrl:iconSet2G+x+".png",
      iconSize: [20,20],
      iconAnchor: [13,5],
      popupAnchor: [13,5]
    });
  }else{
    x = x+10;
    if(x == 100){
      x = 10;
    }
    cm = dtMuc[3][i];
  }
  option = {icon:url, title:dtMuc[0][i], draggable: false};
  latlng = [dtMuc[1][i],dtMuc[2][i]];
    marker = L.marker(latlng, option, {
    renderer: myRenderer,
  });
  arMuc[i] = marker;
  var  mclick = function  (e){
    nMuc = this.options.title;
    alert(nMuc);
  }
    arMuc[i].on('click', mclick);
    layerGroup.addLayer(arMuc[i]);
}
```

var overlay = {'markers': layerGroup};
L.control.layers(null, overlay).addTo(map);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant really follow your code but steps to improve performance are:

1. Use named functions instead of anonymous functions so the function is only defined once and then reused instead for every element (`mclick`).
2. Generate the markers inside a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) in batches
3. I guess not all 10k markers are visible at once so start generating the visible (center) markers first and then the following once and implement a strategy to hide none visible markers.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too much into details that you can find elsewhere, I think that what you need to plan to do is to fetch and populate *only* "the markers that are 'nearby' to the present map-center.  (That is to say, "within, and some comfortable distance out side of, the present *visible* map extent.)

Then, *if* the user relocates the map-center or visible-boundaries significantly, use an AJAX call of some kind to fetch a new marker-list and replace it on the fly.  (Put up a "spinner" cursor-icon to cue the user while you're doing that.)

This, of course, is very similar to the technique that the map software itself uses to depict an "unlimited" map.